# Include file into entire project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, include

is there any way to include one file into entire project?
I want to have some globals and macros accessible from any file in project, but i do not really write #include in every file
TY

Comment: Do you use precompiled headers? Then you could put your globals/macros into the stdafx.h

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Visual Studio project settings:

**Projekt Properties->Configuration Properties->C/C++->Advanced->Forced Include Files**

This will use the specified include files in every source file.

[MSDN Forced include](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c5ztk84.aspx)

---

Alternativ:

If you use precompiled headers you could also add your globals/macros to the stdafx.h